# phonegap 3.0 iOS Project Creation Issues

Tags: ios, macos, cordova

I'm creating a new PhoneGap app using newly released PhoneGap3.0. I followed the  guide located [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-line%20Interface) as best i could. I was able to get the command **./cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld** to work fine, and even the subsequent cd hello (obviosly).

However, whenever I attempt any other entries after it, I continually get the error *cordova: command not found.* I'm sure this is a "me" issue, but help walking through this would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, I'm doing this on a MAC, btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`./cordova` means "execute the cordova binary that is in the current directory"

The "." means "this directory"

Then you say you changed directories by typing "`cd hello`"

Now you are no longer in the same directory as the cordova binary.

You could execute the binary in the parent folder by running `../cordova`

The ".." means "the parent directory," which is the directory "above" your current, working directory.

Comment: thanks for the mini-tutorial. per the documentation noted above, you're supposed to just type *cordova* ... but I kept receiving the same error as noted above so I simply tried something else

Comment: The documentation probably assumes or believes cordova was going to be installed in a location specified in your $PATH.

Type echo $PATH to see all the directories in your $PATH variable. Executable binaries in these locations do not have to have their path specified when you execute them, which would make PhoneGap's documentation accurate from your perspective. For whatever reason, though, your cordova isn't globally accessible. As long as you specify the path to cordova every time you execute it, it will work fine.

Comment: That was immensely helpful. I went back to terminal and ensured I was at the topmost level and reran the commands that the documentation said I should. all things worked like a charm.

Comment: I guess when you open up terminal, it doesn't default to topmost level. Not that I would have even thought that necessary until your assistance. Thanks again.